# How to make an array of string (String has json data)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I Want to make a string like below

`contentlist=["{\"id\":\"id1\"}"]`

How can i achieve this ?

I tried with `NSString` method `stringWithFormat:@"contentlist=[\"%@\"]`
 but it has `\` character when you copy that string and paste it into textedit or in stickies or anywhere.

if you `print` this line that it will display like `contentlist=["{"id":"id1"}]` that i dont want.

Edited :

Here is my code..

```
NSString *stringUrl = <MY SERVER URL STRING>
NSString *param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"contentlist=[%c%@%c]",34,header,34];

NSData *postData = [param dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSError *error;
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:stringUrl parameters:nil error:&error];
req.timeoutInterval= 40.0;

[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[req setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req setHTTPBody:postData];
```

And my `header` value is..

```
{\"id\":\"21ca7309\",\"indexVersion\":0,\"modified\":1501694202014,\"created\":1501691797232,\"modifiedBy\":\"42bebd87be6ddd4a\",\"name\":\"abcd\"}
```

How my param value look like in `debug` mode..

```
@"contentlist=[\"{\"id\":\"21ca7309\",\"indexVersion\":0,\"modified\":1501694202014,\"created\":1501691797232,\"modifiedBy\":\"42bebd87be6ddd4a\",\"name\":\"abcd\"}\"]
```

And how I need to pass is like :

```
contentlist:["{\"id\":\"21ca7309\",\"indexVersion\":0,\"modified\":1501694202014,\"created\":1501691797232,\"modifiedBy\":\"42bebd87be6ddd4a\",\"name\":\"abcd\"}"]
```

Comment: you wan't to convert json string to array??

Comment: I am not getting what you want from your question.

Comment: What is 34 here ?

Comment: @MikeAlter that is a ascill code equivalent to "...I tried with ascii character also.. you can check in this url http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/double-quotes-quotation-mark-speech-marks-ascii-code-34.html

Comment: You need to pass it in to array ? , then use like NSArray *arr = @[header] , and then try to use `dataUsingEncoding` on array

Comment: you mean to say that convert NSArray to NSData and then NSString ?

Comment: Yes Give a try ...

Comment: NSArray *json = @[header];
    
    NSData *mapPointsData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:json];
    NSString *modelJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:mapPointsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];     getting nil value of modelJSON

Comment: Did you try to pass array directly to parameter of  AFJSONRequestSerializer

Comment: @MikeAlter No because API's content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150941/discussion-between-apple-and-mike-alter).

Answer (score 3):

You don't required to use `stringWithFormat`

as you mentioned you have `NSData` of `JSON` if you don't have that then convert it using

```
NSError *error;
NSData *data =  [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:yourJSONO options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

Don't forgot to check  **error** before use :)

you can easily get string from that with below code

```
NSString *str = [[NSstring alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```